# Spring REST endpoint with varying query parameter type

Tags: java, spring, rest

I was wondering about how to implement a REST endpoint in Spring Boot so that it will return a list of objects based on two criteria, which will be lists of values or the word "ALL".

For example: I want to retrieve a list of users that come from any of given countries (I want to provide a list of String typed country codes as a query param) AND that are part of any of given groups (I provide a list of Long typed ids of groups). That would look kind of like this:

```
 @GetMapping("users")
public List<UserDto> findUsers(
        @RequestParam("countries") List<String> countryCodes,
        @RequestParam("groupIds") List<Long> groupsIds) {
    return matchingService.findMatchingUsersBy(groupIds, countryCodes);
}
```

Then my request would look like for example:

```
/v1/users?countries=US,UK,GE&groupIds=1,4,5,6
```

Now, what if I am expected to make it work when one or both parameters are 'ALL' as well, like this:

```
/v1/users?countries=ALL&groupIds=ALL 
/v1/users?countries=UK,FR&groupIds=ALL
/v1/users?countries=ALL&groupIds=1,2,3
```

The expectation here is that the application will fetch all possible values from the DB and search based on that.

I am pretty sure that I would get an exception saying that "ALL" is not a valid Long value for List groupIds.

Is there a way to provide different implementation for the same endpoint based on different Query Parameter type?
What is the cleanest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to retrieve data on the basis of specific country codes and group ids, no need to pass any thing just need to make requestParams optional and handle this on code.

```
 @GetMapping("users")
 public List<UserDto> findUsers(
    @RequestParam("countries", required = false) List<String> countryCodes,
    @RequestParam("groupIds", required = false) List<Long> groupsIds) {
if(countryCodes == null){
    countryCodes = fetchCountryCodeFromRepo();
}
if(groupIds == null){
    groupIds = fetchGroupIdsFromRepo();
}
return matchingService.findMatchingUsersBy(groupIds, countryCodes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution will be to pass String ALL and than first line in your Controller should be:

```
List<String> countries;
if(countryCodes.contains("ALL")) {
  List<String> countries = countryRepository.findAll();
} else {
  countries = countryCodes;
}
matchingService.findMatchingUsersBy(groupIds, countries);
```

Also, you can make `@RequestParam(required = false)` so if you receive null instead of `groupIds` you know that you should include all groups. But this is also so much customization. Client of this API will not be sure if sending nothing to api means "all groups" of "none of the groups". It have to be documented very well if you go with "ALL" solution or "not required" solution. If your use case allows it, cleanest way is to send 100 Strings in list of countries or groups if required.

Comment: yeah, right, but this would work for countries only, since groupIds expects a list of Longs, and String 'ALL' cannot be cast to Long

Comment: Hm, then you should send some "special value" like -1 for groups and ask if groupIds contains -1. But I would not suggest you to use those special values -1 and "ALL". If your use case allows it, it is much better to send 100 countries and 100 groups than special values since someone in the future will be pretty confused and it can happen that in some future someone will assign -1 as a valid group key ID. 100 values are not performance problem if you are concerned about that.